# when i click notification open another my application

Tags: java, android

when i'm in my application,i click my application's notification open another my application,there are two same application on screen and btw i'm create notification from intent service

```
private void sendNotification(String msg, int msgdifferent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("......")
                    .setContentText(msg).setContentInfo(msgdifferent + "");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("Update", "YES");
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
 PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
 mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean every notification open new activity. So i think you forgot to add this steps as referred from [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html)

```
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity=""
```

and also set your resultIntent flags like

```
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```